# PhoneGap and WP7 doesn't want to load code

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I setup Visual Studio Express and PhoneGap 1.4.1 for WP7.
I am able to run the sample template so I starting to move my app code from Eclipse/Android to the VSE www folder. The JQ/JQM doesn't seems to load. So to troubleshoot, I create a new project and put a alert("hello"); inside function onDeviceReady() and the alert dialog did not show.

What is wrong here?!

[image: PhoneGap WP7]

Comment: Move the phone? Does it make a diff? I tried nothing ><

Comment: Nothing, it's just the sample template code from PhoneGap (PhoneGapStarter.zip). I just put the alert in the function onDeviceReady(). Basically http://phonegap.com/start#wp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I see. WP7 (and iPhone) are stricter than Android and need a Alert Callback for it to work

Try the following:

```
function alertDismissed() {
    // do something or nothing
}

function showAlert() {
    navigator.notification.alert(
        'The Message!',
        alertDismissed,      
        'The Title',
        'ButtonName'
    );
}



<body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Nice, your code works ok. Now I have a question. I already have a working PhoneGap app and the aim for PhoneGap is to use standard html code for "write one run many". Because WP7 doesn't have build.phonegap support I am setting up VSE to get the WP7 version.

So does that mean I have to rewrite my code to suit WP7? Even simple alert dialog? I am using JQM now I'm seeing less light.

Comment: You won't have to Rewrite EVERYTHING, but you may have to rewrite some minor things. There are somethings while developement that work in on OS and doesnt work in another. Youll have to see as you go.

Comment: Please more this as correct and upvote if you can. If you have any other questions feel free to ask on StackOverflow

Comment: I understand if they are function calls but for standard javacode such as alert dialog WP7 doesn't handle it the standard way? The funny thing is that if browser IE can navigate mobile site or standard web site why is that not happening in phonegap/wp7? Ofcos it is not a qns directing to you :) but it was a qns that came into my mind.

Comment: It's not WP7 it's the stupid HTML wrapper you are using. iOS has the same issue.

Comment: Can you tell more more about the HTML wrapper? I like WP7 really but I also want to make sure I pick the right framework for mobile development. I'm now on phonegap+jqm.

Comment: I recommend sticking to the native OS language and framework. By using a wrapper that claims to work under all OS's you'll always find issues. I never used HTML in my apps all my apps are native. It's a quick learn to do things right

Comment: Yes, I started with native and seem like html5 is the future. I am able to start converting very quickly but the other platform build by phonegap doesn't seems to behave the same. The WP7 on phonegap seems to have it's own mind. I am not using any plugin other than javascript. JQM+PhoneGap are listed full support for my developing platform.